# EF Core Complex Query Method

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The code is returning reviews based on users like status order. It seems it executes a lot of SQL queries, so do you think it can be simplified and can it be a headache to server performance?

```
ret = _dbEntitySet.AsNoTracking()
           .Where(p => p.PostId == postId && p.IsPublished)
           .Include(p => p.UserLikes)
           .OrderByDescending(p => p.UserLikes.Select(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like).Count() - p.UserLikes.Select(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike).Count())
           .Skip((reviewPageIndex - 1) * reviewPageSize)
           .Take(reviewPageSize)
           .Select(p => new PostModalReviewDisplay()
           {
               CommentCount = p.Comments.Count(),
               DislikeCount = p.UserLikes.Where(q => q.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike).Count(),
               LikeCount = p.UserLikes.Where(q => q.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like).Count(),
               IsCurrentUserDisliked = p.UserLikes.Any(w => w.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike && w.UserInfoId == currUserId),
               IsCurrentUserLiked = p.UserLikes.Any(w => w.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like && w.UserInfoId == currUserId),

               Content = p.Content,
               Id = p.Id,
               UserInfo = new UserInfoExtraSmall()
               {
                   AppUserId=p.UserInfo.AppUserId,
                   Name=p.UserInfo.Name,
                   Surname=p.UserInfo.Surname,
                   ProfileImage=p.UserInfo.ProfilePicture.SmallPath
               }
           })
```

Comment: Nothing better than to check generated SQL then they query plan and then measure...

Comment: My guess is that ef-core isn't smart enough yet to translate the nested counts into one SQL statement and auto-switches to client-side evaluation, i.e. n+1 queries.

Comment: Have you tried to transform `OrderByDescending(p => p.UserLikes.Select(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like).Count() - p.UserLikes.Select(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike).Count())` to `Select(p => new { Obj = p, CountProperty = p.UserLikes.Select(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like).Count() - p.UserLikes.Select(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike).Count() }).OrderBy(p => p.CountProperty)`?

Comment: @GentianKasa I did not try it, but I dont think it is going to work.

Comment: @GertArnold so do you think this query can be simplified by using raw SQL or stored procedure or smth.?

Comment: Just one question: doesn't `p.UserLikes.Select(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like).Count() - p.UserLikes.Select(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike).Count()` (present in the `GroupBy` method) always return `0`? Is it meant to be `p.UserLikes.Where(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like).Count() - p.UserLikes.Where(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike).Count()`?

Comment: Sorry, it's `OrderByDescending` and not `GroupBy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment of mine, it's possible that there's a bug in the code. The `OrderByDescending(p => p.UserLikes.Select(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like).Count() - p.UserLikes.Select(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike).Count())` call should always sort on a single value, `0`. The call should be equal to `OrderByDescending(p => p.UserLikes.Count() - p.UserLikes.Count())` because the `Select` method does not filter values.

That being said, I'll consider it as `OrderByDescending(p => p.UserLikes.Where(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like).Count() - p.UserLikes.Where(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike).Count())` from here on out. If this is not the case let me know and I'll delete this answer.

I see that you count likes and dislikes a couple of times in your queries, in the `OrderByDescending` method and in the `LikeCount` and `DislikeCount` properties in the final `Select`. Keeping in mind this consideration I'd change the query in the following:

```
ret = _dbEntitySet.AsNoTracking()
       .Where(p => p.PostId == postId && p.IsPublished)
       .Include(p => p.UserLikes)
       .Select(p => new { DbEntity = p, LikeCount = p.UserLikes.Where(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like).Count(), DislikeCount = p.UserLikes.Where(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike).Count() })
       .OrderByDescending(p => p.LikeCount - p.DislikeCount)
       .Skip((reviewPageIndex - 1) * reviewPageSize)
       .Take(reviewPageSize)
       .Select(p => new PostModalReviewDisplay()
       {
           CommentCount = p.DbEntity.Comments.Count(),
           DislikeCount = p.DislikeCount,
           LikeCount = p.LikeCount,
           IsCurrentUserDisliked = p.DbEntity.UserLikes.Any(w => w.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike && w.UserInfoId == currUserId),
           IsCurrentUserLiked = p.DbEntity.UserLikes.Any(w => w.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like && w.UserInfoId == currUserId),

           Content = p.DbEntity.Content,
           Id = p.DbEntity.Id,
           UserInfo = new UserInfoExtraSmall()
           {
               AppUserId=p.DbEntity.UserInfo.AppUserId,
               Name=p.DbEntity.UserInfo.Name,
               Surname=p.DbEntity.UserInfo.Surname,
               ProfileImage=p.DbEntity.UserInfo.ProfilePicture.SmallPath
           }
       })
```

One more thing that comes to mind is to switch the comparison clauses in the `IsCurrentUserDisliked` and `IsCurrentUserLiked` properties. Note that the two versions could be the same in terms of performance, depending on the execution plan that the query optimizer generates, but personally I prefer to put the most selective comparison clause first.

So, the final version would be the following:

```
ret = _dbEntitySet.AsNoTracking()
       .Where(p => p.PostId == postId && p.IsPublished)
       .Include(p => p.UserLikes)
       .Select(p => new { DbEntity = p, LikeCount = p.UserLikes.Where(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like).Count(), DislikeCount = p.UserLikes.Where(f => f.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike).Count() })
       .OrderByDescending(p => p.LikeCount - p.DislikeCount)
       .Skip((reviewPageIndex - 1) * reviewPageSize)
       .Take(reviewPageSize)
       .Select(p => new PostModalReviewDisplay()
       {
           CommentCount = p.DbEntity.Comments.Count(),
           DislikeCount = p.DislikeCount,
           LikeCount = p.LikeCount,
           IsCurrentUserDisliked = p.DbEntity.UserLikes.Any(w => w.UserInfoId == currUserId && w.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Dislike),
           IsCurrentUserLiked = p.DbEntity.UserLikes.Any(w => w.UserInfoId == currUserId && w.LikeStatus == LikeStatus.Like),

           Content = p.DbEntity.Content,
           Id = p.DbEntity.Id,
           UserInfo = new UserInfoExtraSmall()
           {
               AppUserId=p.DbEntity.UserInfo.AppUserId,
               Name=p.DbEntity.UserInfo.Name,
               Surname=p.DbEntity.UserInfo.Surname,
               ProfileImage=p.DbEntity.UserInfo.ProfilePicture.SmallPath
           }
       })
```

As a final thought, I agree with @AdrianoRepetti's comment:

> Nothing better than to check generated SQL then they query plan and then measure...

Check the generated query plan for different versions and use the query that best suits your needs.

Comment: Hmm. I've implemented your final version but it is throwing an error which I did not understand.  `Query source (from UserReviewLike f in value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable"1[fso.Core.Domains.MMEntities.UserReviewLike])) has already been associated with an expression.'` do you know why this may be throwing error.

Comment: It works like charm, I was getting error from other action. Thanks.